# Did Paul imply that angels differed in their tongues according to 1-cor 13:1

Tags: word-study, 1-corinthians, angels, language

> 1 Corinthians:13.1  Though I speak with **the tongues of men and of
>   angels**, but have not love, I have become sounding brass or a
>   clanging  cymbal.

The word tongues in the passage is the greek word glossa. Here is the Thayer Definition.

> G1100
>
> Original: γλῶσσα
>
> Transliteration: glōssa
>
> Thayer Definition:
>   **The language or dialect used by a particular people distinct from that of other nations**

God divided the tongues of men in Gen 11:7. 
But in this passage, Paul uses the plural "tongues" in a way that suggests a multiplicity of languages among angels in the same way it exists among men.

**QUESTION: 
1) Did paul think angels differed in their tongues?**

a) If yes, how could he have arrived at such a view.

b) Was there anything in the Pharisaical doctrines of the day to support his phrasing of 1-cor 13:1?

Comment: Why why. This is an important question to me. You just down vote irresponsibly without offering any justification.

Comment: I need to know why you down voted so that I can improve on future questions.

Comment: I down voted this question because it can only be answered based on opinion.

Comment: The primary meaning of γλῶσσα is "tongue". It is part of the basic vocabulary of Greek, It can also mean "language", but this is a secondary meaning.

Comment: The word "tongues" could just as easily be plural so as to include men. It doesn't say "tongues of angels."

Comment: Asking if angels have tongues is a very different question from asking whether *Paul* thought angels have their own language(s) and what his basis for this might be. We don't deal with the former here, but could help with the latter.

Comment: @Bagpipes thanks for giving me your reason.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @Dan I've rephrased the question. But I'm not good at greek so I don't know whether I can safely imply the existence of diverse angelic tongues according to that verse.

Comment: @user20490 no need to be good at Greek. Our users can help with that. I think the question is better / on topic now. Unfortunately I see no way to vote to reopen on mobile app

Comment: @Dan  ok. Good to know that it's on topic now. I hope you guys will vote it out of the hole it's in now.

Comment: While I was going to see about re-opening this question, in doing so, I seem to have [found a possible duplicate](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8599/1-corinthians-131-tongues-of-men-or-angels-meaning) and so have left it closed (though I up-voted this Q - this question was better asked and I would prefer it to stand as areference to the other question).

Comment: @user20490 - [Nothing could be further from the truth](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/why-are-questions-closed-on-this-site).